# How to convert Given time HH:mm from UTC to different timezone in Java8?

Tags: java, java-8

I want to convert the given HH:mm from UTC to different time zones.

```
String myDateString = "02:30";
LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.parse(myDateString, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm"));
int hour = localTime.get(ChronoField.CLOCK_HOUR_OF_DAY);
int minute = localTime.get(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR);
int second = localTime.get(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_MINUTE);

System.out.println("UTC Time is "+ hour + ":" + minute);

Calendar pstTime = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"));
hour = pstTime.get(hour);
minute = pstTime.get(minute);
```

getting error with this. any help appreciated.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   30

Comment: Why are you mixing up `java.time` and `java.util.Calendar`? Stick to `java.time`.

Comment: On what *date* do you want to convert the time? Time by itself can't be converted "to a different timezone", because whether you're in DST or not depends on the date.

Comment: Please add more info on exception

Comment: LocalDateTime.withZoneSameInstant("America/Los_Angeles");

Answer (score 2):

As already said, a time zone without day part misses information considering DST.

So it is:

```
    String myDateString = "02:30";
    LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.parse(myDateString, 
            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm"));
    LocalDateTime localDateTime = localTime.atDate(LocalDate.now());
    System.out.println("localDateTime: " + localDateTime);
    ZonedDateTime zonedDateTimeUTC = localDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
    System.out.println("zonedDateTimeUTC: " + zonedDateTimeUTC);

    ZonedDateTime zonedDateTimePST = zonedDateTimeUTC.withZoneSameInstant(
            ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles"));
    System.out.println("zonedDateTimePST: " + zonedDateTimePST);

    int hour = zonedDateTimePST.getHour();
    int minute = zonedDateTimePST.getMinute();
    int second = zonedDateTimePST.getSecond();
```

There is no need for the old `Calendar` class.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should specify date too. For that problem you can use this block of code

```
    DateTimeFormatter DATE_TIME_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter
            .ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy'T'HH:mm z");
    String inputValue = "08/03/2020T15:20 UTC";
    ZonedDateTime zdtInstanceAtOffset = ZonedDateTime.parse(inputValue, DATE_TIME_FORMATTER);
    ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = zdtInstanceAtOffset.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles"));
    System.out.println(zonedDateTime);
```

Comment: If you need exactly HH:mm you can append to inputValue property from front "08/03/2020T" and from end " UTC" texts and at the end from  the zonedDateTime object get hour and minute.

Answer (score 1):

Without a date, you can convert a time, given for one timezone, to another timezone only by adding/subtracting the time difference between the source timezone and the target timezone to/from the given time.

The problem with this approach is, that the time difference between timezones is not constant over the year, when it is identified by "region/location" (like "America/Los Angeles"). If you use "EST" or "GMT" or "CET" (sometimes referred to as "zone times") instead, the differences would be stable – but you are still inaccurate: several timezones will have two zone times, depending on the time in the year …

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `java.time.ZonedDateTime` class for this and the method `withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId zone)` which returns a copy of the datetime in the specified zone.

Here is an example if your input time is in UTC timezone. To change the zone of the input time change `Zone inputZone` to `ZoneId.of("<your timezone>");`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String timeString = "02:30";

    // Change this to the zone of the input time
    ZoneId inputZone = ZoneId.of("UTC");

    // Parse your input into time
    LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(timeString);

    // Add current date to the time, you can add custom date using LocalDate.of(int year, int month, int dayOfMonth)
    LocalDateTime localDateTime = time.atDate(LocalDate.now());

    // Declare zoned date time with input zone specified
    ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = localDateTime.atZone(inputZone);


    // Declare zones you will use
    ZoneId myZone = ZoneId.systemDefault();
    ZoneId utcZone = ZoneId.of("UTC");
    ZoneId nyZone = ZoneId.of("America/New_York");
    ZoneId tokyoZone = ZoneId.of("Asia/Tokyo");

    // Get times in different timezones
    ZonedDateTime myDateTime = zonedDateTime.withZoneSameInstant(myZone);
    ZonedDateTime utcDateTime = zonedDateTime.withZoneSameInstant(utcZone);
    ZonedDateTime nyDateTime = zonedDateTime.withZoneSameInstant(nyZone);
    ZonedDateTime tokyoDateTime = zonedDateTime.withZoneSameInstant(tokyoZone);

    // Print the times in different timezones
    System.out.println("My Timezone: " + myDateTime);
    System.out.println("UTC: " + utcDateTime);
    System.out.println("NY: " + nyDateTime);
    System.out.println("Tokyo: " + tokyoDateTime);

    // Print without the offset
    System.out.println("My Timezone: " + myDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME));
    System.out.println("UTC: " + utcDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME));
    System.out.println("NY: " + nyDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME));
    System.out.println("Tokyo: " + tokyoDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME));
}
```

This code will generate the following output:

```
My Timezone: 2020-03-11T03:30+01:00[Europe/Zagreb]
UTC: 2020-03-11T02:30Z[UTC]
NY: 2020-03-10T22:30-04:00[America/New_York]
Tokyo: 2020-03-11T11:30+09:00[Asia/Tokyo]
My Timezone: 2020-03-11T03:30:00
UTC: 2020-03-11T02:30:00
NY: 2020-03-10T22:30:00
Tokyo: 2020-03-11T11:30:00
```

Comment: if I add below snippet to get only HH:mm from the date time, getting the strange output. not sure is this expected. 
        sout("My Timezone: " + myDateTime.getHour() + ":" + myDateTime.getMinute());
        sout("UTC: " + utcDateTime.getHour() + ":" + utcDateTime.getMinute());
        sout("NY: " + nyDateTime.getHour() + ":" + nyDateTime.getMinute());
        sout("Tokyo: " + tokyoDateTime.getHour() + ":" + tokyoDateTime.getMinute());   
UTC: 2020-03-12T19:05:00
NY: 2020-03-12T15:05:00
Tokyo: 2020-03-13T04:05:00
My Timezone: 0:35
UTC: 19:5
NY: 15:5
Tokyo: 4:5

Comment: To output in HH:mm format you can use the format method like this `myDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm")`